# Unable To Clean Url In Search Bar Core Php Through Htaccess Redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I  have made a search box that displays 2 colums
THe url comes like this

`https://www.example.com/hs-code?searchcode=01&search=animals`
I want it to display like
`https://www.example.com/hs-code/01/animals`

The htaccess rule I used for it is below

```
## Remove extensions 
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]  
## Redirect from extensions to non-extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^hs-code/(.*)/(.*) /hs-code.php?searchcode=$1&search=$2
```

But its still unable to do it
when i search in the searchbar the url that shows is
`https://www.example.com/hs-code?searchcode=01&search=animals`
but if i manualy enter the url it shows the correct url that i want
`https://www.example.com/hs-code/01/animals`
I want to make it come automatically when i search in the searchbar

Comment: Did you ask the question in a reverse way?

Comment: There is no `hs-code.php` in the URL you posted, is that a typo?

Comment: @brombeer yeah , i actually redirected the .php to clean url like www.example.com/hs-code with this code in ht access                                                                                                   
 `## Remove extensions
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

## Redirect from extensions to non-extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
`

Comment: @nice_dev nope i want clean seo friendly urls for my website

Comment: Please post relevant code _in your question_ and not as a comment. Thanks. What doesn't work? How do you assemble the URL? Do you get an error (on screen or in your server logs)?

Comment: @brombeer done...hope it helps

Comment: Ok. If your search form uses the `GET` method when you submit you'll always end up with an URL like `/hs-code?searchcode=01&search=animals`. Either use Javascript to intercept form submission and assemble your desired URL or redirect in PHP

Comment: @brombeer okay so how do i do that

Comment: There are probably tons of tutorials/pages out there that explain that. In PHP, you can use [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect: `header("Location: xyz.php");`

Comment: Why are you regex matching the clean URL then?

Comment: @nice_dev yes it is see i have updated my question

Comment: _"but if i manualy enter the url it shows the correct url that i want"_ - but submitting your form doesn't do the same thing, as you manually entering the desired URL. Submitting the form is what creates the `?searchcode=01&search=animals` query string in the first place. [...]

Comment: [...] So either you will have to _redirect_ that URL format to your desired format first, and then rewrite that _second_ request coming in with the "correct" format to the version with URL parameters again. Or you intercept the form submission on the client side with JavaScript, assemble the "correct" format based on the form field values, and then assign that as the new URL.

Comment: @brombeer hey thanks bro its done , i did it by javascript..